# Windows authentication in SSIS package

Tags: ssis

I am working on my first SSIS package that connects to a SQL server. While I am developing it, I am connecting using Windows authentication which works fine since my Windows user name was added to the security of the database I am working on. Now, my IT department created a service account to deploy the package with. My question is, how can I change the user name/password of the connection before I deploy it? Is there a configuration file that the connection can read from? How can this be handled?

Comment: What version and deployment model (Package or Project) of SSIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually have two security contexts here to be concerned with.  The first is the account required to deploy the package or project you've created.  The second is the account required to be able to execute the package you've created.

**End-to-end Windows Authentication (deployment, execution and data sources)**

The deployment account would need to have correct permissions to the server or filesystem on which it will reside.  The execution account may be configured with a very different set of permissions, primarily related to the permissions required to execute whatever tasks you've built into the package.

In order to deploy the package under a different user that your own, it may be as simple as opening an application (like Command Prompt, Windows Explorer or SSIS Deployment Utility) as that user account and moving the package to the correct location.  This can be handled on your workstation or the server.

For the execution account, you have options depending on how you're going to operationalize the execution of the package.  Here's a few scenarios:

- If you will have the package be executed by the SQL Server Agent and the account you need to execute the package with is the SQL Server Agent service account, you only need to create the job to run the package.  Unless otherwise programmed, packages called from a SQL Agent job will run as the SQL Agent account
- If you will have the package be executed through a SQL Server Agent job and the account you need to use for executing the package is NOT the SQL Agent service account, you can create an SSIS Proxy Account and specify that in the SSIS Package execution job step.  After creating the credential inside SQL Server, it is as simple as changing a dropdown.
- If you will be using command line execution from a SQL Agent job, the above two scenarios are still applicable.
- If you will be using another mechanism (like Windows Scheduler or another Enterprise Scheduling tool) that uses a command line execution-like method, you should still be able to have that process "run as" the execution account.

**Windows Authentication for deployment and execution only (SQL authentication for data)**

The above details still apply for executing SSIS packages via jobs and/or command line, but you will need to pass the username and password to the connection manager at the time the package runs.  You have several options to do this and should follow any established patterns or standard your organization has in place.  SSIS has long supported using an XML-based .dtsConfig file which can be read into the package at run-time.  There is a GUI within SSDT/BIDS that will lead you through the process of creating the file and telling it which package properties you want it to be able to configure.

**A word of caution**

Be careful when you're trying to SAVE sensitive information inside SSIS packages.  There is a property named PackageProtectionLevel which can be set at the project and package level.  By default, it is set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.  Now, don't let this property trick you into thinking the entire package is encrypted.  It is not.  This setting specifically refers to how SSIS will handle properties that are typed as sensitive.  For example, the passwords in the connection managers are typed as sensitive information.  SSIS will encrypt that field so that it doesn't store passwords in plain text.  But it ONLY pertains to saving/storing the package.  You can pass in plain text through a variable or configuration file that will be read into a sensitive field (like a password) at run-time.

If you need to be able to save a password with the package you've developed, I would recommend changing the PackageProtectionLevel to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and setting it to something your team is able to remember or uses to protect other assets.  Once that setting is in place,  you will be able to check the "Save Password" box within the connection manager and have that go where ever the package goes.  If you don't need to save that password with the package, change the property to DontSaveSentitive.  Like I mentioned, you can still pass in credentials through configurations or other means, but it won't be stored INSIDE the package itself.